# add zero to make all subsets the same size then sum them up and show in excel

Tags: python, sum, combinations

I wrote a code where it will take data from an excel file and generate all the combinations of the data. I am able to do this but i want to add 0 in the subsets where there are less number so that all the subsets have equal number of values. Then i want to add all the subsets and place the value at the end of each subsets. Then i want to send it to an excel file. Any idea of how to achieve it. Wil be of great help. Thank you for your time.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
df = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/Desktop/Dc Resistance/Book1.xlsx').parse('Frequency,Voltage, Line')
x=[]
x.append(df['Resistance'])
y= np.array(x)
z=y.flatten()
print(z)
result = [seq for i in range(len(z), 0, -1) for seq in 
itertools.combinations(z, i)]
print(result)
col = 0
for row, data in enumerate(result):
worksheet.write_row(row, col, data)
workbook.close()
print (result)
```

the output comes as follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtZvC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Zdv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the excel sheet back and use fillna:

```
df = pd.read_excel('c:\\somefolder\\data.xlsx')
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
#this will create columns that sum the rows
df['sum_rows'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df.to_excel('newdata.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Could you kindly suggest me or suggest me an example code of how to add all these numbers in each row and have it at the last column. Thank you again. was really helpful.

Comment: The code above will fill the excel from col A to H where there is no value. You do not need more than this if I understood your requirement correctly? just put the path of your excel file to read and the name of excel file to write.